# How can I design text with "span" using .insertAdjacentHTML in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is what I think is has to look like:

```
    toggleText.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeBegin', '<span style="color:white">');
    toggleText.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeBegin', partvalue[partvalue.length-1]);
    toggleText.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeBegin', '</span>');
```

But when I execute the function, I get this in HTML:

```
<span style="color:white"></span>
"Text from partvalue.length-1"
```

This is what I would like to use, but I know it is not working like this. What can I do?:

```
    toggleText.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeBegin', '<span style="color:white">'partvalue[partvalue.length-1]'</span>');
```

Comment: You have to concatanate your string:  `toggleText.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeBegin', '<span style="color:white">' + partvalue[partvalue.length-1] + '</span>');` - this would be clear if you used your browser console / developer tools - it would show you had a syntax error.

Comment: Right. InsertAdjacentHTML expects a complete piece of HTML. The first parameter is an incomplete span. That is all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to `concatenate` it properly in order to make it working,

```
 toggleText.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeBegin', 
       '<span style="color:white">' + partvalue[partvalue.length-1] + '</span>');
```

In javascript, for string concatenation `+` have to be used.